# Error: Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool

Tags: android, flutter, dart-pub

I'm a newbie in flutter, what should I do in this case?
Thank you all.

**This is the Error message**

> Error: Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds... (9 tries left)
> Error on line 14, column 6 of pubspec.yaml: Expected ':'.
>
> dds: 2.0.4
> ^

and in the **line 14**, it's a comment out like this

```
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
```

I can't figure it out what cause this error

This is my `pubspec.yaml` file

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_auth: ^3.1.4
  cloud_firestore: ^2.5.3
  firebase_core: ^1.8.0
  firebase_storage: ^10.0.6
  provider: ^6.0.1
  image_picker: ^0.8.4+3
  file_picker: ^4.1.6
  transparent_image: ^2.0.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.8
  qr_code_scanner: ^0.5.2
  cupertino_listview: ^2.0.0
  zefyr: ^0.12.0

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  image_picker_for_web: ^2.1.4
  firebase_storage_web: ^3.0.4
  shared_preferences_web: ^2.0.2
  url_launcher_web: ^2.0.4


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/images/
```

When I use `flutter` command, it always jump out
**This is the Error message**

> Error: Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds... (9 tries left)
> Error on line 14, column 6 of pubspec.yaml: Expected ':'.
>
> dds: 2.0.4
> ^

Comment: The pubspec.yaml looks fine, try `flutter pub get`

Comment: I tried. but still jump out this error. Error: Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool.

Comment: `flutter clean && flutter run` if nothing works `flutter pub cache repair `

Comment: Sadly. It always jump out the error: `Error: Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds... (9 tries left)
Error on line 14, column 6 of pubspec.yaml: Expected ':'.`

Comment: try deleting comment line 14

Comment: it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Under dependencies in your yaml file make sure you add this line. Your carrot symbol should come after colon and right before number like so. Also be aware of indentation in yaml file.

dds: ^2.0.4